# Assigning values to global variables in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am new to Lisp and I am trying to understand how variables and assigning variables work. I am trying to check if a given number is 5 or not. If it is, it is supposed to change it to 10 and print it. If not it just tells you that it is not 5 but my code below is not working.

```
(print "Give me a number")
(setq *x* (read))

(defun check(*x*)
    (if (= *x* 5) (setq *x* 10) (format t "~d is not 5" *x*))
)

check(*x*)
print(*x*)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `check(*x*)` and `print(*x*)` isn't Lisp syntax. Replace that with `(check *x*)` and `(print *x*)`
- Your function operates with some `*x*`, but it *isn't* your global `*x*`, but local variable`*x*` from argument list. Don't name function arguments same as global variables. Check this example:

```
(defparameter a 8)
(defun add (a)
  (setf a (+ a 2))
  (print a))
(add a)
(print a)
```

Returned values are 10 and then 8. Compare it with:

```
(defparameter *a* 8)
(defun add (a)
  (setf *a* (+ *a* 2))
  (print *a*))
(add *a*)
(print *a*)
```

Returned values are 10 and 10.

- Don't use `setf` or `setq` for creating variable, these functions are only for setting new value. Use [defparameter](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defpar.htm#defparameter) or [defvar](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defpar.htm#defvar) instead.
- This code assigns value to global variable:

```
(print "Give me a number")
(defparameter *x* (read *query-io*))
(defun check ()
  (if (= *x* 5)
      (setf *x* 10)
    (format t "~d is not 5" *x*)))
(check)
(print *x*)
```

- You can also do this task without global variables.

```
(print "Give me a number")
(defun check (n)
  (if (= n 5)
      (setf n 10) 
    (format t "~d is not 5" n)) 
  (print n))
(check (read *query-io*))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I compile a file with this definition in SBCL:

```
(print "Give me a number")
(setq *x* (read))

(defun check(*x*)
    (if (= *x* 5) (setq *x* 10) (format t "~d is not 5" *x*))
)
```

There are two warnings:

```
warning: undefined variable: *X*
```

This is located at the global `setq`, because `setq` does not *declare* global variables. So the compiler does not know any global variable named `*x*`.

Then, inside the function:

```
style-warning:
 using the lexical binding of the symbol (*X*), not the
 dynamic binding, even though the name follows
 the usual naming convention (names like *FOO*) for special variables
 --> PROGN SB-IMPL::%DEFUN SB-IMPL::%DEFUN SB-INT:NAMED-LAMBDA
 ==>
   #'(SB-INT:NAMED-LAMBDA AAAB::CHECK
         (*X*)
       (DECLARE (SB-C::TOP-LEVEL-FORM))
       (BLOCK CHECK
         (IF (= *X* 5)
             (SETQ *X* 10)
             (FORMAT T "~d is not 5" *X*))))
```

This is pretty self-explanatory, but here the binding is lexical.

This is however not a property of `defun`, this is because there is no declared special variable named `*x*`.

If instead, you use `defvar` or `defparameter`, there is no warning (e.g. `(defvar *x* 0)`). The same goes if you only declare the variable as special: `(declaim (special *x*))`, before you define the function that binds it.

Inside the function, assuming `*x*` is declared as a special variable, the bindings works as a `let`, which means you can use special variables as function parameters. In your case this does not change much because you only set the current binding with the inner `setq` (the parameter shadows the global binding), so in effect this is a lot like a lexical variable.

But you can use a special variable to rebind dynamically a parameter:

```
(defun foo (*a*) ...)
```

This is the same as:

```
(defun foo (a)
  (let ((*a* a))
     ...))
```